# Javascript conflict in Magento 2.1

Tags: javascript, php, magento2.1

I am using an External javascript in the magento2 Block. That external javascript is calling its own jquery library. And this is conflicting with the Magento jquery.

Now, am getting this errors:

> 1. Uncaught TypeError: $.widget is not a function
> 2. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'timepicker' of undefined
> 3. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initObserversForPopup' of undefined

Please help me Resolving this issue.

I also try to add this external js at the Head section and at the end of body tag.

Regards,

Comment: try jQuery.noConflict(); after including the external js library.

Comment: @jasmin_makasana I did that under the external js. But still same issue.
Am adding external js under Blocks.

Comment: is it possible for you to add those js or url here?

Comment: `code` <script id="signupScript"  crossorigin="anonymous" async="" defer="defer" xml="space" src="//static.ctctcdn.com/js/signup-form-widget/current/signup-form-widget.min.js" src_type="url" /> `code`   

Added this code in Block section at the admin. Also tried to add this at head and body section inside code file.

Comment: It is very hard to check the issue :( Sorry, You have to provide some kind of demo or code snippet or more info related to this issue.

Comment: `code`
<div class="ctct-inline-form" data-form-id="5cddd086-2917-4eb8-8ed2-e085317bff0e"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" xml="space">// <![CDATA[
 var _ctct_m = "e53edb9edc0445e261952f955b11f324"; 
// ]]></script>
<script id="signupScript" src="//static.ctctcdn.com/js/signup-form-widget/current/signup-form-widget.min.js" async="" defer="defer" type="text/javascript" xml="space"></script>
`code`  
This is the constant contact form script.